# Non uniform texture access in vulkan glsl

Tags: c++, graphics, shader, vulkan, compute-shader

I am trying to write a compute shader that raytraces an image, pixels on the right of the yz plane sample from image A, those on the left from image B.

I don't want to have to sample both images so I am trying to use non uniform access by doing:

`texture(textures[nonuniformEXT(sampler_id)], vec2(0.5));`

and enabling the relevant extension in the shader. This triggers the following validaiton layer error:

```sh
Message: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkShaderModuleCreateInfo-pCode-01091 ] Object 0: handle = 0x55a1c21315d0, name = Logical device: AMD RADV RAVEN2, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0xa7bb8db6 | vkCreateShaderModule(): The SPIR-V Capability (SampledImageArrayNonUniformIndexing) was declared, but none of the requirements were met to use it. The Vulkan spec states: If pCode declares any of the capabilities listed in the SPIR-V Environment appendix, one of the corresponding requirements must be satisfied (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.182.0/linux/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkShaderModuleCreateInfo-pCode-01091)
```

If I read the [docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkPhysicalDeviceDescriptorIndexingFeatures.html) it would seem this is a hardware feature, but someone said I can still have non uniform access if create the correct extension object. But I am not entirely sure how to do that.

Comment: Does your GPU have feature `SampledImageArrayNonUniformIndexing`?

Comment: it seems it does, the value I read from:
`PhysicalDeviceFeatures`

Is set tot true

Comment: And have you enabled the feature when creating the device?

Comment: Ah I understand now, one must use the pnext entry when creating the logical device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enable the feature at device creation.

You can check for support of  the feature by calling [vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures2](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-khr-extensions/html/chap38.html#VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures2) <sub>[archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20230320132319/https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures2)</sub> and following the `pNext` chain through to a [VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan12Features](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-khr-extensions/html/chap38.html#VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan12Features) <sub>[archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20230320132319/https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan12Features)</sub>, and checking that `shaderSampledImageArrayNonUniformIndexing` member is to `VK_TRUE`.

After that when creating the device with [vkCreateDevice](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-khr-extensions/html/chap5.html#vkCreateDevice) <sub>[archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20230320132319/https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#vkCreateDevice)</sub>, inside the `pCreateInfo` structure, in the `pNext` chain you have to have a [VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan12Features](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-khr-extensions/html/chap38.html#VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan12Features) <sub>[archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20230320132319/https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan12Features)</sub> with `shaderSampledImageArrayNonUniformIndexing` set to `VK_TRUE`.

```
bool checkForNonUniformIndexing(VkPhysicalDevice physicalDevice)
{
    VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures2 features;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures2(physicalDevice, &features);

    if(features.sType != VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_FEATURES_2)
    {
        return false;
    }

    const VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures2* next = &features;

    do
    {
        // We know the type of the struct based on the `sType` member, but the first 
        // two fields are the same in all of these structs. There may be a more appropriate 
        // generic structure to use, but as long as we don't access any further members
        // we should be mostly fine.
        next = reinterpret_cast<const VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures*>(next->pNext);
        if(next.sType == VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_VULKAN_1_2_FEATURES)
        {
            const VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan12Features* pVk12Features = reinterpret_cast<const VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan12Features*>(next);
            return next.shaderSampledImageArrayNonUniformIndexing == VK_TRUE;
        }
    } while(next);

    return false;
}

VkDevice* createDevice(VkPhysicalDevice physicalDevice, const VkAllocationCallbacks* pAllocator)
{
    VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan12Features features;
    features.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_VULKAN_1_2_FEATURES;
    features.shaderSampledImageArrayNonUniformIndexing = VK_TRUE;

    VkDeviceCreateInfo createInfo;
    createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO;
    createInfo.pNext = &features;
    // Setting other create data

    VkDevice device;
    vkCreateDevice(physicalDevice, &createInfo, pAllocator, &device);

    // Error checking

    return device;
}
```